# Where can I download SSMS 2016?

Tags: ssms

Currently I use SSMS 17, however Gearhost, the website I am trying to deploy my database to, currently only use SQL Server version 13, which I believe to be SSMS 16.

The exact error is;

> Error restoring database The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 14.00.1000. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 13.00.4451. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server.

Is there a place I can download this older version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms#previous-ssms-releases):

> The SSMS 17.x installation does not upgrade or replace SSMS versions 16.x or earlier. SSMS 17.x installs side by side with previous versions so both versions are available for use. If a computer contains side by side installations of SSMS, verify you start the correct version for your specific needs. The latest version is labeled

You can **download** it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms#previous-ssms-releases)

Comment: Previous SSMS version downloads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-ssms-releases

Answer (score 1):

MSFT currently (May 2020) provides versions of SSMS back to 16.5.3.

Please use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2016#previous-ssms-releases) for the **overview**. The **download** of version SSMS 2016 can be found [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946).

Answer (score 1):

The error being encountered is due to an attempt to restore a SQL Server 2017 database to a SQL 2016 instance.  It's not an issue with SSMS versions.  SQL databases are not backwards compatible.  You can restore a backup from an older version instance to a newer version instance (2016 to 2017), the restore will perform the upgrade, but you cannot restore a backup from a newer version instance to an older version instance (2017 to 2016 for example).

Answer (score 0):

To download older versions of SSMS you need to go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and select the version at the top of the left nav bar, otherwise it defaults to the latest version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

here, click on the version!

> Microsoft docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-ssms-releases

[image]